fetch all the items present in the document folders in a SharePoint site
I need to fetch all the items present in the document folders in a SharePoint site , when i tried with a PowerShell Script throttles as below site libraries have lakhs of items to fetch. Long running script leads to out of memory .We tried different scripts but it failed at some point.
Is there any PowerShell script which can help to fetch large items without any error  or any other tools which is easier than PowerShell script
PowerShell scripts
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.SharePoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\DocumentInventory.csv"
$global:DocumentInventory = @()
$Pagesize = 2000
  
#Function to scan and collect Document Inventory
Function Get-DocumentInventory
{
     [cmdletbinding()]
    param([parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $Web)
    
    Write-host "Getting Documents Inventory from Site '$($Web.URL)'" -f Yellow
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Web.URL -Interactive
 
    #Calculate the URL of the tenant
    If($Web.ServerRelativeUrl -eq "/")
    {
        $TenantURL = $Web.Url
    }
    Else
    {
        $TenantURL = $Web.Url.Replace($Web.ServerRelativeUrl,'')
    }
  
    #Exclude certain libraries
    $ExcludedLists = @("Form Templates", "Preservation Hold Library","Site Assets", "Pages", "Site Pages", "Images",
                            "Site Collection Documents", "Site Collection Images","Style Library")
                                
    #Get All Document Libraries from the Web
    Get-PnPList -PipelineVariable List | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.Title -notin $ExcludedLists -and $_.ItemCount -gt 0} | ForEach-Object {
        #Get Items from List  
        $global:counter = 0;
        $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $_ -PageSize $Pagesize -Fields Author, Created, File_x0020_Type,File_x0020_Size -ScriptBlock `
                 { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($_.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Documents from '$($_.Title)'" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($_.ItemCount)";} | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
        Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Documents from Library $($List.Title)" -Completed
      
            #Get Root folder of the List
            $Folder = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property RootFolder
  
            #Iterate through each document and collect data          
            ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
            { 
                #Collect document data
                $global:DocumentInventory += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
                    SiteName  = $Web.Title
                    SiteURL  = $Web.URL
                    LibraryName = $List.Title
                    ParentFolder = $Folder.ServerRelativeURL
                    FileName = $ListItem.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
                    FileType = $ListItem.FieldValues.File_x0020_Type
                    FileSize = [math]::Round($ListItem.FieldValues.File_x0020_Size/1KB)
                    AbsoluteURL = "$TenantURL$($ListItem.FieldValues.FileRef)"
                    CreatedBy = $ListItem.FieldValues.Author.Email
                    CreatedAt = $ListItem.FieldValues.Created
                    ModifiedBy = $ListItem.FieldValues.Editor.Email
                    ModifiedAt = $ListItem.FieldValues.Modified
                })
            }
        }
}
   
#Connect to Site collection
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
     
#Call the Function for Webs
Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb | ForEach-Object { Get-DocumentInventory $_ }
    
#Export Documents Inventory to CSV
$Global:DocumentInventory | Export-Csv $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
Write-host "Documents Inventory Report has been Exported to '$CSVPath'" -f Green


Please don't use local words like lakh here. Not everyone understand them.
